# Spring-batch ignoring rows processed before encountering skippable Exception

Tags: spring-batch

Hi I am new to Spring batch and using version 3.0.4.RELEASE for my POC to process a very large flat file as below.

1. Running the batch in chunk processing mode.
2. A custom reader delegate with synchronized methods to run the
3. A custom processor which validates and tranforms the data.

The file format is as below.

`COB_DATE   HIERARCHY_NODE_ID   HIERARCHY_LEVEL MEASURE CURRENCY    VALUE
20151009    329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Position_60d    USD 21848543.55
20151009    329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Position_90d    USD 9040531.7
201510009   329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Ratio_30d       47.0069727152
20151009    329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Ratio_60d       20.2442137613
20151009    329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Ratio_90d       121.7425393354
20151009    329715  COSTCENTER  TOV_Turnover_30d    USD 259996659.00`

I have a validation on the COB_DATE field, and in the processor I am throwing an ValidationException if the format is incorrect. 
The **problem** is all the valid rows before the validation exception was thrown are skipped and unavailable for the writer. In this case row1 and row2.

Here is the job configuration

```
<beans:import resource="JobContext.xml" />

    <!-- Starting point of the feed runner -->
    <beans:bean id="feedJobRunner" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.FeedJobRunner" >
            <beans:constructor-arg name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
            <beans:constructor-arg name="job" ref="feedJob"/>
            <beans:constructor-arg name="feedDao" ref="feedDao"/>
    </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="feedReader" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.FeedReaderDelegate" scope="step">
       <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
                <beans:property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['inputResource']}"/>
                <beans:property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/>
                <beans:property name="lineMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                        <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
                            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                                <beans:property name="delimiter"  >
                                    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB" />
                                </beans:property>
                                <beans:property name="names" value="#{jobParameters['fieldNames']}"/>
                                <beans:property name="strict" value="false"/>
                            </beans:bean>
                        </beans:property>
                        <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper" >
                            <beans:bean class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.FeedFieldSetMapper"/>
                        </beans:property>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
       </beans:constructor-arg>
   </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="feedProcessor" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.FeedRowProcessor" scope="step" >
        <beans:constructor-arg name="feedDao" ref="feedDao" />
        <beans:constructor-arg name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="feedWriter" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.FeedWriter" scope="step">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <job id="feedJob">
            <step id="importFeedStep">
                <tasklet task-executor="stepExecutor" throttle-limit="10">
                        <chunk reader="feedReader" processor="feedProcessor" writer="feedWriter"  commit-interval="300"  skip-limit="100"  >
                           <skippable-exception-classes>
                                <include class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.exception.FeedValidationException"/>
                            </skippable-exception-classes>

                            <listeners>
                                    <listener>
                                            <beans:bean class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.listener.FeedSkipListener">
                                                <beans:property name="feedDao"  ref="feedDao"/>
                                            </beans:bean>
                                    </listener>
                            </listeners>
                        </chunk>
                </tasklet>
                <listeners>
                    <listener >
                        <beans:bean id="feedStepListener" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.listener.FeedStepListener">
                            <beans:constructor-arg name="feedDao" ref="feedDao" />
                        </beans:bean>
                    </listener>
                </listeners>
            </step>

        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <beans:bean id="feedJobListener" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.listener.FeedJobListener">
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="processDao">
                        <beans:bean class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.dao.JdbcProcessDao">
                            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:constructor-arg>
                </beans:bean>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
        <validator ref="jobParamValidator"/>
    </job>

    <beans:bean id="stepExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

    <beans:bean id="jobParamValidator" class="com.ubs.risk.arisk.job.batch.validation.JobParameterValidator"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This is the default Spring Batch "Skip Mechanism" behavior. I suggest you read §5.1.5 through §5.1.7 and §6.3.2 through §6.3.3 of the Spring batch documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: Thank you.I know its a bit late to respond on this. I understood the concept and modified the code as per my requirement.